# Controls/Design Pattern to use for an iPad app with two levels of tables leading to a detail view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an e-commerce site I'm trying to produce an iPap specific app for and am struggling with the best way to recreate the menu structure. We have a top level menu that lists product categories. Clicking on that displays the list of products in the selected category. Clicking on the product takes you to the product detail page.

It seems like a great place for a UISplitViewController but I'm struggling with the two levels of browsing.  Should I do a single table controller for the product categories taking you to a UISplitViewController with the product list and product detail? Or just two separate tableviews leading to a normal view and not mess with the splitview?  How have other app handled this?  I'm honestly not that much of an iPad user, so I'm not familiar with how other apps have done this type of thing.

Comment: that sounds exactly like what Apple's Mail does on iPad (given you have >1 mailboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design with the `UISplitViewController` is what you should go for. You can then deal with your hierarchy incode more or less like you would on an iPhone with a plain navigation controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to only target iOS 6+ you could wait and use the UICollectionView.  Then you could implement something similar to the photos app on the iPad with pinching/zooming and turning of products (instead of photos).  The WWDC 2012 videos have examples to view and go through example code.

If you have to target iOS 4+, UISplitView will also do the job in a more straightforward fashion.